# Referenced foreign key id is null when inserting new values in the second table. How do I simply select the id from the first table to the second?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I have created two tables in my Database Manager

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    super.onConfigure(db);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
{
    database.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    // create table
    String sql = "create table "
                + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + C_LIST_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + C_LIST_NAME + " VARCHAR(255))";
    Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");

    //create second table
    String sql2 = "create table "
                + TABLE_NAME_ITEMS + " ("
                + C_LIST_ITEM + " VARCHAR(255), "
                + C_DATE + " text, "
                + C_FLAG + " integer, "
                + C_LIST_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), "
                + C_ITEM_ID + " integer, foreign key "
                + "("+C_ITEM_ID+")" + " references " +TABLE_NAME+ "("+C_LIST_ID+"))";
    Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate second database");

    database.execSQL(sql);
    database.execSQL(sql2);
}
```

This is how I am inserting the data into the second table. In the tables themselves, the foreign key IDs are null. How do I bring the id from the first table to the second when creating a new item with the same C_LIST_NAME?

```
public void insertItemData(String item, String listName)
{
    Integer listNameId = getListId(listName);
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(C_LIST_ITEM, item + listNameId);
    contentValues.put(C_LIST_NAME, listName);
    database.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME_ITEMS, null , contentValues);
    Log.d(TAG, "insertData: data has been inserted in items");
}
```

Comment: Sqlite is not mysql!

Comment: I truly meant SQLite not MySQL it was a late night oops

Answer (score 0):

I should've rested last night after trying to figure this out for hours.
I figured it out and the solution was very simple. I was just too tired to think I guess.

In case anyone is curious, I just need to insert it like this:

```
public void insertItemData(String item, String itemDescription, String listName)
{
    baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
    database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME_ITEMS+
                    "("+C_ITEM_NAME+"," +C_ITEM_DESCRIPTION+ ", " +C_LIST_NAME+ "," +C_DATE+ "," +C_FLAG+ "," +C_ITEM_ID+ ")"
                    + "VALUES ('"+item+ "', '"+itemDescription+ "', '" +listName+ "', '" +baseActivity.getCurTime()+ "', '" +0+ "', "
                    + "(SELECT " +C_LIST_ID+ " FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "
                    +C_LIST_NAME+ "=?))",
            new Object[]{listName});
    Log.d(TAG, "insertData: data has been inserted in items");
}
```